# Can't get ConEmu and Python Poetry to play nicely with each other

Tags: conemu, python-poetry

When I type something like:

> poetry --version

I get in ConEmu:

> Poetry version ←[36m1.1.4←[0m

This makes Python Poetry unusable as there are codes all over the place instead of text.

Even though I have enabled the settings Inject ConEmuHk and ANSI and xterm sequences in ConEmu settings.

I tried reinstalling both but nothing seems to fix this.

[example of the isssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6pES.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. My workaround is to invocate poetry with:

```
poetry ... --no-ansi
```

This disables whatever coloring or whatever poetry is trying to do and failing on conemu.